# Generate a thousand team sites from a spreadsheet and associate them to a hub site

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, modern-experience, hub-site

As a part of testing out some functionality on my local SharePoint Online tenant, I would like to provision the creation of about 2,000+ modern Team Sites (not attached to a group) based on a list of names that is in a spreadsheet (can easily be converted to CSV, txt, JSON, whatever makes this task easier).

I would like to iterate through the list of Site Names, create the site, then after the site is created associate it to an existing Hub site that I have created.

Firstly, is this even possible, and if so, could someone point me in the right direction on how I might achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: Why is this a remotely good idea? Maintaining 2000+ sites is a nightmare and I'm having trouble believing there is a situation where it would be necessary.

Comment: A brash comment from someone with zero context. When you have a lot of documents, and you do not want to hit the limits of SharePoint Online, you do not have many options. If you want a central location to access documents, the recommendation from Microsoft is to use Sites Collections. Moving the 2,000 Sites to 2,000 Document Libraries within a site creates an equal nightmare, even more so when you break inheritance on folders within the document libraries.

Comment: Fair enough, @Ushka. I personally would avoid using SPO for that application if possible, but of course sometimes it is not possible to pick your own tool. 2000 sites and hitting the SPO limit would seem to imply literally millions of files, after all, or fewer very large ones.